# How do I search for anything between these tags

Tags: search, sed, grep

How do I search for anything between these tags, I would like to list all occurences where there is some value between the f:facet xml element

```
<f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if every `f:facet` tag is on a separate line then you can do like this:

```
cat file.xml | sed -ne 's/<f:facet[^>]*>//;s/<\/f:facet>//p'|grep Name
```

if you want to look across multiple files you can do:

```
find . -type f| xargs sed -ne 's/<f:facet[^>]*>//;s/<\/f:facet>//p'
```

Comment: apologize if I was not clear, I would like to do a blanket search across all files which could contain any text (not just name) between the facet elements

Comment: I get the following error message, not sure what I am missing here. sed, find, xargs are getting picked up from the cygwin installation on my Windows machine.

c:\>find . -type f| xargs sed -ne 's/<f:facet[^>]*>//;s/<\/f:facet>//p'
The specified path is invalid.

Comment: @Samuel: you have to use double quotes on windows instead of single quotes

Answer (score 1):

This will list whatever occurs between the `<f:facet>` tags:

```
sed 's/<f:facet[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<\/f:facet>/\1/'
```

This test:

```
echo '<f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>' | sed 's/<f:facet[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<\/f:facet>/\1/'
```

Outputs this:

```
Name
```

To run it on all files in the current directory:

```
sed 's/<f:facet[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<\/f:facet>/\1/' *
```

To run it on all files in all directories under a common one:

```
find /path/to/common -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed 's/<f:facet[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<\/f:facet>/\1/'
```

If you're running `find` from a Windows CMD.EXE prompt, you're probably getting the Windows `FIND.EXE` which is giving you that error message. Try `find --help` and `find /?`. The former is GNU `find` and the latter is Windows. If the former gives you an error message and the latter gives you help text, then that will confirm the problem.

You will need to start an instance of Cygwin instead.

Comment: thanks, there was an issue between the find program in windows / cygwin